# Pandas: Multiindex with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe which `ID_1`, and `ID_2` are my indexes:

```
ID_1 ID_2 feature_1 feature_2 
  1    1      0        0
       2      1        1 
  2    1      1        1 
       2      0        1
```

What I want to get is the data With `ID_1 = 1` and `feature_2 = 1` 
Which is:

```
ID_2 feature_1 feature_2 
  2      1        1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tuples` with double `[]` for one row DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.loc[[(1,2)]]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc[[pd.IndexSlice[1,2]]]
```

---

```
print (df1)
           feature_1  feature_2
ID_1 ID_2                      
1    2             1          1
```

If use only one `[]` get `Series`:

```
s = df.loc[(1,2)]
print (s)
feature_1    1
feature_2    1
Name: (1, 2), dtype: int64
```